# can we use sets for more randomness?

Tags: python, random, set

python random module uses time as the seed (right?), which is predictable, and sets are displayed in random order so if we use sets and random module and time module together, will it result in more randomness? and is it less predictable?

a code like this:

```
import random
from typing import Union
import time


def get_random_item(iterator: Union[set, list, tuple], seed=None):
    iterator = set(iterator)
    if seed is None:
        seed = time.time() / 10 ** (len(str(int(time.time()))) - 1)
    seed = int(((seed ** seed ** random.random() ** random.random()) * (10 ** random.randrange(9, 16))) % len(iterator))
    return list(iterator)[seed]
```

Comment: Sets do not have a random order, they simply have no defined order but it is VERY far from being random.

Comment: The seed depends on the OS. If it provides a source of randomness (e.g. `/dev/urandom`) it will be used.

Comment: "and sets are displayed in random order " No, they do not have a random order. They are *unordered* data structures, and the order that they have is *consistent (within a python process)* but *arbitrary*

Comment: Note that multiplying multiple randoms will change the randomness in a way that you do not understand, adding more randoms actually makes things less random. Do not play around with it unless you very good reason to and have actual criteria you are trying to fulfill, other than "needz more randomness".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- read the docs on the limitations of the random module: [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)

> **Warning**
>
> The pseudo-random generators of this module should not be used for
> security purposes. For security or cryptographic uses, see the [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets)
> module.

2- read [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets) documentation (emphasis is mine):

> The secrets module is used for generating cryptographically strong
> random numbers suitable for managing data such as passwords, account
> authentication, security tokens, and related secrets.
>
> In particular, **secrets should be used in preference to the default
> pseudo-random number generator in the random module, which is designed
> for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography.**

3- remember that trying to invent your own cryptography is <s>usually</s> **almost always** [a bad idea](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43272/why-is-writing-your-own-encryption-discouraged) (unless you have the expertise for it)

4- conclude

- do not use sets to try to improve randomness in a cryptographically secure way
- use proven solutions when security is needed